# Problem publishing azure static web app (blazor wasm) via devops because it's referencing nuget packages from remote source (not nuget.org)

Tags: azure, web, static, blazor, devops

I have a blazor web assembly app and it references a few nuget packages that exist as Artifacts in our Azure Devops source control.  This web app gets published as an azure static web app.  Everything works great if the blazor app only has package references to nuget.org but if I add a package from our devops artifacts, the app will not publish.  Here is the error:

/working_dir/src/BlazorUI/BlazorUI.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Ovcri.AspNetCore.Authentication. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
/working_dir/src/BlazorUI/BlazorUI.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package Ovcri.AspNetCore.Authentication.Extensions. No packages exist with this id in source(s): nuget.org
Failed to restore /working_dir/src/BlazorUI/BlazorUI.csproj (in 2.66 sec). | 1 | Please build your app locally before publishing. | https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-dotnetcore?pivots=platform-linux

I would think that something in the .yml file could instruct the build process to look in our devops as well as nuget.org but I have not been able to find anything.

I've read this but could not find a solution:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example

Also Googled, of course.

Answer (score 0):

- I have tried a sample blaze with CI/CD pipelines instead of  `DeVops`  follow the below steps.
- First, we need to create an azure static web app in azure portal as shown below.

[image]

- Give the repository details that you are using if we use  `GitHub`  and you can also use  `AzureDevops`  as below.

[image]

- Select the  `Blazer`  as the Build Presets as below and click on  **Review+Create**  as below.

[image]

- - Thanks to  `@Swimburger`  for the  [repository](https://github.com/Swimburger/AzureSwaBlazorWasmDemo/actions).
- After Clicking on  `review+Create`  it will deploy a Static web app an after run a CI/CD pipeline as below.

[image]

- After Successful deployment open the URL in static web it will redirect to as below.

[image]